# Convergence of alternating sequence (Proof)

Tags: analysis

[image]

$S_{2n+1} \ -\ S_{2n-1} < 0 $ is what I'm struggling to understand

I don't understand where the inequality comes from. I've tried hard to understand it but it's not coming to me unfortunately.

[image: My Workings]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just write down the sums and you will see it as in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $(s_n)$ is the sequence of the partial sums of $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Hence,

$$
s_{2n+1}-s_{2n-1} = x_{2n+1} +x_{2n} = \frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n} <0.
$$

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense.  So you add the $2n+1_{th}$ term and the $2n_{th}$ term. So why is there a negative infront of the $1/2n$

Comment: The terms have alternating signs: $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just note the following:

- You have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}a_k$ with $a_k \downarrow 0$
- Specifically $a_k > a_{k+1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

So, it follows
$$S_{2n+1} = S_{2n-1} - a_{2n} + a_{2n+1} = S_{2n-1} - \underbrace{(a_{2n} - a_{2n+1})}_{>0} < S_{2n-1}$$